# Has anyone tried to statically link the Postgres client libs into a project?

Tags: linker, static-libraries, c++builder

I'm using Embarcadero® C++Builder 11 Version 28.0.44940.9541.  Windows 11.

I am building a 32 bit client, using FireDac, for a customer that is using Postgres.  I've tried dropping the actual PG 32 bit lib's in the project folder and adding them to the project in the IDE as well as using the #pragma statements in code, again with the libs in the project folder. The project folder is included in the Dirs and Conds. in the project options.

I have already converted the libs below to OMF using the coff2omf from Embarcadero, due to the COFF linker complaints.

```
#pragma link "iconv.lib"    
#pragma link "libintl.lib"    
#pragma link "libpq.lib"    
#pragma link "libcrypto.lib"    
#pragma link "libssl.lib"
```

When I move the executable to client machine, it fails with the can't find vendor client lib.

AS a side note, I need to statically link as the customer would rather not have other files distributed with the software.

Edit:
I need to statically link either 32 or 64 bit postgres libraries into my executable and need help as to how to get this done?

Comment: Are you sure you are using 32 bit libraries? Recent edition of postgreSQL (which I use with 64 bit C++ builder app and FireDAC) are 64bit only.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Roger, yes I am using the 32 bit versions, I've had them for sometime and you can 'dl them from the https://www.enterprisedb.com/download-postgresql-binaries.

Comment: Community, thank you for the inquiry.  My specific problem is that I unable to get the Postres driver libs to statically link into my executable, despite all the normal routes as described above.  I need advice on how to, or why the linker will not, statically link the PG libs in C++ builder IDE so that I don't need to distribute the PG dll's with my app.  I hope this is a better description of my question.

Comment: Hi Roger, are you linking the 64 bit postgres libs statically in your project or using the dll's when you distribute your app?

Comment: With FireDAC all you do is specify the full path location of the postgreSQL file libpq.dll (on my PC it's at \Program Files\Postgresql\13\bin\libpq.dll. As long as the end user has postgreSQL installed then it all works. So I suppose this means that I am not statically linking.

Comment: Thank you Roger, yeah if you're building the program with the FireDAC FDDrivers.ini / FDConnectionDefs.ini files then you are dynamically linking your program.  The DLL will provide the called functions, therefore it is not statically linked.  You need to get the .LIB files instead of the .DLL's and then normally just add them to your project no matter what directory they live in and it will link the needed functions into the executable, thus no installation of PostgreSQL on the client.  FireDAC allows you to build temporary or private connections that are not stored in the .ini files.